Body / Mind – why are they different?
In Buddhism it's mostly all about mind training. The mind is regarded as a skhanda/aggregate separate from the body. Also, feelings, consciousness and karmic conditions. Now I am in doubt, thinking that the body could produce the mind. If so, that would mean, that the Buddhist path is stripped of many implications, like that we are wandering in samsara since beginningless time. Could someone please provide some links or explanations which explain the Buddhist argumentation that body and mind are separate "entities"/ aggregates. Thank you.

The human body is but only one type of physical bodies that includes animal bodies. There are bodies made of energy such as those of devas. And those of higher realms are said to be mind-made. But regardless, all bodies are host for the mind and not the cause of the mind.

Now I am in doubt, thinking that body could produce mind. Then mind would get destroyed when people die. That would be against whole buddhist ideology. That's because, then there can't be rebirth, karma, hell or heaven, Nirvana, bodisathwa, Paramitha , ect. Mind being different entity from body is a main axis of Buddhism.

Then there won't be Buddha and Buddhism. One of main evidence normal person can observe for proving as evidence for mind being different entity is the rebirth. (people/children who can remember last life). But if someone achieve Dhayana, they can observe / understand themselves that mind is different entity. (by observing rebirth, past lives, others minds).

Purification of View (diṭṭhi-visuddhi):
The correct seeing of mentality-materiality constitutes purification of view.
A fundamental thing about the Buddha's teaching is that it teaches about conceptual reality and ultimate reality. So conceptually, you can say that your foot is a foot and your thought is a thought but ultimately, they are made up of experience happening, right now, in the present moment from moment to moment and are impersonal.
From CHAPTER XVIII of The Pathe of Purification

"*30. Hence the Blessed One said: “There are two kinds of view, bhikkhus, and
when deities and human beings are obsessed by them, some hold back and some overreach; only those with eyes see. And how do some hold back? Deities
and human beings love becoming, delight in becoming, rejoice in becoming.
When Dhamma is taught to them for the ceasing of becoming, their minds do
not enter into it, become settled, steady and resolute. Thus it is that some hold back. And how do some overreach? Some are ashamed, humiliated and disgusted by that same becoming, they are concerned with non-becoming in this way:


‘Sirs, when with the breakup of the body this self is cut off, annihilated, does not become any more after death, that is peaceful, that is sublime, that is true.’ Thus it is that some overreach. And how do those with eyes see? Here a bhikkhu sees what is become as become*. Having seen what is become as become*, he has entered upon the way to dispassion for it, to the fading away of greed for it, to its cessation. This is how one with eyes sees”

*The phrase "Here a bhikkhu sees what is become as become" and “having seen what is become as become” essentially points towards recognizing and understanding the nature of existence and phenomena as they truly are, right here, right now in the stream of impersonal moment by moment experience AKA Samsara.
https://edhamma.github.io/vism/sphinx/build/html/ch-18.html


does body make a mind, or mind make a body? why?
how are they different - mind and body?

The answer to the first question should answer the second question, since if one is generating the other, then you infer they are not the same.
According to one discourse of the pali cannon:

When their mind has become immersed in samādhi like this—purified,
bright, flawless, rid of corruptions, pliable, workable, steady, and
imperturbable—they project it and extend it toward the creation of a
mind-made body. From this body they create
another body, physical, mind-made, complete in all its various parts,
not deficient in any faculty.

So here the direction is from mind to body, but still this may leave you in doubt.

From DN 9

“Then what do you make of this: ‘The cosmos is finite …’ “‘The cosmos is infinite …’ ‘The soul and the body are the same thing …’ ‘The soul and the body are different things …’ … ‘A realized one still exists after death …’  ‘A realized one no longer exists after death …’ ‘A realized one both still exists and no longer exists after death …’ ‘A realized one neither still exists nor no longer exists after death. This is the only truth, anything else is wrong’?”
“This too has not been declared by me.”


“Sir, if they were to ask me this, I’d answer like this, ‘The reincarnation I had in the past was real at that time, and those of the future and present fictitious. The reincarnation I will have in the future will be real at the time, and those of the past and present fictitious. The reincarnation I have now is real at this time, and those of the past and future fictitious.’ That’s how I’d answer.”
“In the same way, while in any one of the three reincarnations, it’s not referred to as the other two, only under its own name.



Body / Mind – why they are different?

Because, It's their nature.

Now I am in doubt, thinking that body could produce mind.

Then mind would get destroyed when people die. That would be against whole buddhist ideology. That's because, then there can't be rebirth, karma, hell or heaven, Nirvana, bodisathwa, Paramitha , ect. Mind being different entity from body is a main axis of Buddhism.
Then there won't be Buddha and Buddhism. One of main evidence normal person can observe for proving as evidence for mind being different entity is the rebirth. (people/children who can remember last life). But if someone achieve Dhayana, they can observe / understand themselves that mind is different entity. (by observing rebirth, past lives, others minds).
Now lot of western (no offense) people will think, above arguments are just imaginary thinking of Asian people. (as some stupid people / ideology). No offence again.
So look at below research evidence. They (people who did the research) are not Asian. They aren't related to Buddhism. They didn't use guess work or imaginary work. They used sciencetifc methods.
Researches 1
Researches 2

In Western culture, these type of statements often get dismissed as fantasy even though they might contain something other than pure imagination. It is probably best not to repeatedly question the child, nor try to prevent them from speaking about these topics. For more info, please refer to Dr. Tucker’s Advice to Parents.
from Researches 2




reincarnation can't be used to validate the mind exists alone. someone might argue there is no mind without a body, but there is soul that transmigrates

reincarnation can't be used to validate the mind exists alone. yes, you are right. But the thing is nobody can validate it 100% with arguments. I just wanted to disprove his claim Now I am in doubt, thinking that body could produce mind. Theravadins who learned abhidamma doesn't believe the concept of soul.

He already doesn't believe Buddhist ideology. So presenting examples from damma wouldn't help. His view is scientific. So he needs / seek scientific evidence. That's why I used those research resources.

This is my view. I am not arguing. I'm just saying. someone might argue there is no mind without a body, but there is soul that transmigrates That's not correct. There's no soul involved. But there's a cause where mind exist without body. Which is Bahama worlds / realms without body(arupa loka).
